# Какой номер системного вызова имеет создание очереди сообщений?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, nasm

Задача состоит в том, что необходимо создать очередь сообщений на асемблере NASM, продемонстрировать его работу.

Версия ядра Linux 4.10
В идеале хочется получить ответ формата как на этом сайте https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/
В какой регистр и какие записывать значения. Но буду рад любой информации по этой теме. Важно чтобы реализация была сделана на 32х битной разрядности и через прерывания int 0x80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Номер вызова можно брать из дерева исходников ядра, а именно (для x86) [`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl), а параметры из [`include/linux/syscalls.h`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/include/linux/syscalls.h). Номер вызова помещается в EAX, а параметры распихиваются в прямом порядке по регистрам (%ebx, %ecx, %edx, %esi, %edi).

Для создание очереди сообщений необходим вызов `mq_open()`, номер `0x116`. Оный имеет один параметр — буфер с именем очереди, который соответственно передаётся через %ebx. Для манипуляции очередью нужны другие mq_* вызовы.

Создание и манипуляция SysV очередями (`msgopen()` и др.) на x86 эмулируется юзерспейсом.

Вполне можно пользоваться данными с syscalls.kernelgrok.com/. Как только системный вызов попадает в релизное ядро, то номер его не меняется, дабы не поломать ABI. Так что со времён 2.6 они ни чуть не менялись.

Всё вышесказанное подразумевает, что «32х битная разрядность» — это архитектура x86, а не x32-ABI для x86_64.