# Где можно узнать о системные вызовах линукс?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, api, nasm

Занялся NASM, не знаю, где найти информацию о системных вызовах в линуксе, не подскажите источники?

Comment: Практически идентичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765131/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9/765159 , но ИМХО в данном случае сформулирована более общая и более полезная проблема, так что лучше оставить...

Comment: [системные вызовы, определяемые **стандартом posix**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html)

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Номер вызова можно брать из дерева исходников ядра, а именно (для x86) [`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl), а параметры из [`include/linux/syscalls.h`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/include/linux/syscalls.h). Номер вызова помещается в %eax, а параметры распихиваются в прямом порядке по регистрам (%ebx, %ecx, %edx, %esi, %edi) (*для amd64 регистры будут отличаться*).

Кроме того есть несколько поросший быльём [сайтик](https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/), где всё это собрано в табличку, удобную для неофитов и не только. Несмотря на некоторую древность, информация вполне актуальна (опять же для x86).